# Flow to update fields of same records when there is record update Not working

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I have custom object parcel__c there are 8 fields over this object. I have written a flow so that whenever user enter parcelnumber__c values it will get updated same in systemParcelNumber__c. User can enter below values.

```
parcelnumber__c-->systemParcelNumber__c
parcelDate__C--->systemParcelDate__c
```

Issue is flow will copy value correctly but in scenarios where lets suppose parcelnumber__c=100 & parcelDate__C= blank or Null..flow is copying null values also to systemParcelDate__c which is not required. we  want values to be copied only when non null values are there. Is there any we can acheive this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try if condition in flow as described [here](https://www.levelupsalesforce.com/flows-if-statement)?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use multiple Decision elements, or you can use Formulas. For example, using formulas, you could write these two formulas:

```
// NewParcelNumber (Text)

{!BLANKVALUE($Record.ParcelNumber__c, $Record.SystemParcelNumber__c)}
```

And

```
// NewParcelDate (Date)

{!BLANKVALUE($Record.ParcelDate__c, $Record.SystemParcelDate__c)}
```

Then, create an Assignment element that assigns those values:

```
$Record.SystemParcelNumber__c equals {!NewParcelNumber}
$Record.SystemParcelDate__c equals {!NewParcelDate}
```